# How do I colorize class names in code samples in Sand Castle/MAML

Tags: c#, syntax-highlighting, documentation-generation, sandcastle, xml-documentation

I'm migrating to Sand Castle from nDoc to generate the doc for my class reference. nDoc does not support .net 2.0 and has many other limitations.

Earlier, with nDoc, I was able to apply nice coloring to my code, including highlighting of class names.

E.g. `Console.WriteLine(something)` would display `Console` in different color (because nDoc allows you to specify HTML styles directly in XML).

However, Sand Castle (MAML) seems to ignore type names (it accepts only real C# code, HTML attributes for coloring are not allowed, colorization is performed by Sand Castle itself). In the end, only keywords, comments and constants are colorized. Can this be fixed so that type names would be colorized too? Thanks!

The below is what I had with nDoc and what I need to replicate with Sand Castle (`MailMessage`, `Pop3` and `Console` are highlighted).

[image: What I need (and what I already have in nDoc]

Answer (score 0):

If your using the Sandcastle Help File Builder you can manually do it by editing the highlight.xml file under the folder \EWSoftware\Sandcastle Help File Builder\Colorizer\ and add the keywords under the csharp syntax.

Comment: Thanks. But will this high-lighted text appear as a keyword or as a class name? I don't want it to be a keyword-like (keywords are displayed in strong blue while class names have separate color in VS2010, more grayish). Is there a special category for them?